# winform datagrid which enables to insert several lines as new records into database

Tags: c#, winforms, datagrid

I have a question

I am, developing a small program as follows:

I work at a newspaper, we have journalists which write news and articles. By the end of the week they have to send in an invoice which lists the: 1( category (news or article), 2( description (of the piece they wrote), 3) and the amount of characters.

I am looking for a Winforms Datagrid control, in which the writers will be able to make their invoices in a speedy fashion. Of all the grids/controls I see, the insert operation goes one line-item at a time, with the fields in a vertical order one on top the other. I am looking for a grid or other control, where you input info line by line, 10 lines or even more, and (after pressing the submit button at the bottom) each line gets inserted as a separate record into the database or xml file.

I need this type of grid or control for a lot of similar operations, like adding a list of categories and their codes, etc. in all the scenarios I would like to enable my users to insert new records or lines in a database in a bulk fashion. is that possible with a standard Winforms Datagrid

Thanks for helping me

Comment: Even when using the DataGridView you still have control over when the underlying datasource is persisted to the back end database (or otherwise). Are you having a specific problem with persisting multiple records back to the DB ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about Winforms, but the WPF DataGrid allows users to edit multiple rows at once. You can databind the grid directly to the database, so the changes will be updated automatically.